# In a text based adventure game, how do I prevent long confusing conditional code?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am creating a text-based, choose your own adventure game in C++.

In this game, there will be lots of possibilities on where you choose to go, what you choose to do etc.

My question is, how do I prevent this from becoming extremely confusing.

Example:

Lets say at one point in the game you can be asked whether to go to the forest or the desert. If you choose desert, thats a COMPLETELY different story line from the forest.

So how would I prevent from my code looking like this.

```
if (player goes to the desert)advice? { 
    /*Whole story line of the desert*/
else if (player goes to the forest) {
    /*Whole story line of the forest */
```

Inside of these story lines there would be more conditionals like that, and more elaborate story lines, so is there any way that I can write the code for one story line in a separate file, then just run that file for that conditional? Anyways I can do that separately instead of writing everything out inside of the conditionals? If I did that the code would quickly become long and confusing to look at/edit.

I was thinking about doing headers and making functions inside of the headers that write out the story line, so I would just have to type out the function, but if I did that, then I couldnt access the global variables in the game such as `playerName` or `playerRace` etc.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated. I'm new to C++ so please forgive me if I've missed something painstakingly obvious.

Comment: Look into state machines.  Your game story could be represented as such.

Comment: @Alice edited my answer, you need only one class if you use arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a class based solution. The question is quote broad, so not quite sure which design patterns would fit. However, a sample class may be `CrossroadsDesicision` that'll export options `["Go to desert", "Go to city", ...]` and have a method `apply` that should receive an options from the array and return the relevant decision class for the next step

**Edit:** 
The base class should contain:

- possibleDecisions - an array of possible decisions (You could use an option class here, composed of a name (string or enum - you should use templating here) and a description)
- apply - a function receiving a decision, acting on it, and returning the next decision

Comment: So for choosing a race, like you did, I would create a class named RaceDecision, inheriting from a base class Decision (you should know about inheritance). Then, it would have an array of options, each containing a decision name (e.g. 'Elf') and a description. There would be a method that accepts the decision the player wants (from the iostream) and acts on it (in your case, storing the chosen race).

Comment: What would be contained in the base class? The method for applying the decision?

Comment: Edited my comment to answer your question

Comment: I do like this idea a lot and very well might go for it. Although, is there any reason you chose an array? Why not just use variables like `desertDecison` or `forestDecision`, then use the method to apply those?

Comment: Please refresh the page to view the edited version of that comment, which was atrocious.

Comment: I prefer the array to make it generic - for all you know, a decision exposes an array of next decisions, so one decision may have a single follow up (like dying), and another may have multiple

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, I'll get back to coding now!

Answer (score 2):

I am going to expand a little on *Trevor Hickey* state machines proposition, because it is a great idea.

First you need to realize that your story lines can be modeled using a good old graph

1. The independent stories are the element of your game which you consider whole and non dissociable. For instance there is the DesertStory, the ForestStory. They are the nodes, vertices. You should uniquely identify a story, by its name for instance
2. The relationship between the stories are the edges. These edges need to be serializable, which mean being able to be represented both as objects and in some persistent format, and that you can load and save between. Because You want to customize your game, you may want to allow the persistent format to be text based so they can be edited manually and loaded at the start of the game.
3. Now the state machine come from the fact that the transition between a story to another is conditional.

In programming term it may means : a virtual Story class

```
struct Story 
{
     virtual std::string name() = 0;
     virtual int play() = 0;
};
```

A Story Arc, which link between stories. It need a condition to trigger, which can be what the last story returned

```
struct StoryConnection
{
    std::string nameStorySource;
    std::string nameStoryDestination;
    int condition;
};
```

With this you can write individual stories on one side, and then write story arcs separately. You can also adapt and modify the logic of your game by the modifying the story arcs. You can have multiple game play possible, each one being just a group of StoryConnections.

The logic is going to be simple as:

```
Story* s = new InitStateStory; 
while(!endOfGame(s))
{
      int decision = s.play();
      StoryConnection conn = getConnection(s.name(), decision);
      Story* nextstory = creatNextStory(conn.nameStoryDestination);
      delete s;
      s = nextstory;
}
```

Comment: This is an extremely interesting idea, I'm gonna go to my white board and actually try and graph this out. Thank you so much for showing me this in code, i googled state machines but couldnt figure out how I would model such a thing in C++. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to structure your code. So you have a class Player, a class Place, then you need an array to store the places, whatever happens in that place will be handled by a virtual function:

EDIT:

I have changed the code to take care of the destinations, you only need another class if you want to maintain the destinations in a list for easy adding/removing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

class Place;

const int PLACE_TAVERN = 0;
const int PLACE_FOREST = 1;
const int PLACE_DESERT = 2;

const int NUMPLACES = 3;
std::vector<Place *>vPlaces;
Place * Destination[UCHAR_MAX];

class Place {
private:
    bool connections[NUMPLACES]; // This is a simple and inefficient way of doing it: you can also use a linked list with nodes for more flexibility/efficiency
protected:
    int id;  
    void listConnections()
    {
    int n = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<NUMPLACES; i++) {
            if (connections[i]) {
                if (n>0) {
                    std::cout << ", ";
                }
                else {
                    n++;
                }
                std::cout<< vPlaces[i]->name;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
public:
    std::string name;  

  virtual void describe() 
  {
    std::cout << "You are in " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "From there you can go to: " ;
    this->listConnections();
  }
  Place(int p, std::string n, char l) 
  {
    id = p;
    name = n;
    Destination[(int)l] = this;
    for (int i=0; i<NUMPLACES; i++) {
        connections[i] = false;
    }
  }

  void setConnection(int placeId) {
    connections[placeId] = true;
  }

  bool canGoTo(Place *destination) {  
    return (NULL != destination) && connections[destination->id];
  }
};


class Tavern : public Place {
public:
 Tavern() : Place(PLACE_TAVERN, "the (T)avern", 'T') {} // the move letters should be unique
};

class Forest : public Place {
public:
 Forest() : Place(PLACE_FOREST, "the (F)orest", 'F') {}
};

class Desert : public Place {
public:
    Desert() : Place(PLACE_DESERT, "the (D)esert", 'D') {}
  };

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
        Destination[i] = NULL;
    }
  Tavern* tavern = new Tavern();
  Forest* forest = new Forest();
  Desert* desert = new Desert();

  tavern->setConnection(PLACE_FOREST) ; // you can do this manually or maintain an array of bool
  forest->setConnection(PLACE_TAVERN) ;
  forest->setConnection(PLACE_DESERT) ;
  desert->setConnection(PLACE_FOREST) ;

  vPlaces = {tavern, forest, desert};

  Place* currentPlace; 
  Place* newPlace; 

  currentPlace = tavern;
  newPlace = NULL;

  char key = 0;

  do {
    currentPlace->describe();
    std::cout << "Choose a destination by their letter or (q)uit?";
    std::cin >> key;
    do {} while (std::cin.get() != '\n'); // flush keyboard

    newPlace = Destination[(int)key];
    if (currentPlace->canGoTo(newPlace)) {
        currentPlace = newPlace;
    }
    else if (key != 'q') {
        if (NULL == newPlace) {
            std::cout << "You cannot go into the void like that!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "You cannot go to " << newPlace->name << " from " << currentPlace->name << "!" << std::endl;            
        }
        std::cout << "Press Enter to continue...";
        do {} while (std::cin.get() != '\n');
    }
  } while (key != 'q');
  std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

compile with:

```
g++ -o file file.cc -Wall -std=c++11
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enum` and `switch`:

```
class Player
{
    public:
    enum class CurrentLocation {Forest, Desert, Undefined};
    CurrentLocation currentLocation;
    //...
}

//and in checking
switch(player.currentLocation)
{
    case Player::CurrentLocation::Forest:
        //player is in forest
        break;
    case Player::CurrentLocation::Desert:
        //player is in desert
        break;
    default:
        //player is dead or sth
        break;
}
```

You could also wrap everything in classes or functions, and store their addreses in `player` object, so you don't even have to check in what state `player` is, you would just write:

```
class Player
{
    Location* currentLocation;
    public:

    void setCurrentLocation(Location* loc) {currentLocation = loc;}
    Location* getCurrentLocation(void) {return currentLocation;}
    //...
}

//and use it, of course you have to implement Location class/struct
player.currentLocation()->showMap();
```

But choosing good game design is complex subject, not meant to be "simple answer"

Comment: Encoding this kind of stuff into C++ code is complex, difficult to write, difficult to maintain, and error prone. This kind of stuff needs to be data-driven.

Comment: I like the idea of using enums to represent things such as location, but I would still have to write it all out, like what happens in the desert. This question ma have been to vague and you didnt understand it, if so, my fault.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe Raw pointers are ok, there isn't any ownership happening here.

Comment: @Alice Well, that's just about design. But whatever you do, don't create too big hierarchies of inherited classes, it will become messy sooner or later. Pointers aren't bad also for these tasks :)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, I'll get back to coding now!